# How to read YML feeds - or ignore DOCType if read as XML

Tags: c#, xml, yaml

ok i hope this isn t too confusing here goes.

We have been provided a feed by a russian retailer in YML format which i need to read and enter into my database.  I haven t used YML before and to be honest i don't really understand what it is or how it differs from XML (which we prefer using but unfortunately the retailer won t supply it in this format).  I have tried google how to read a YML file and all i come across is YAML which the file that I have been supplied with does not look like.

So as i have not had any luck finding YMl i have downloaded it as a XML and tried to read it but the following line is added:

```
<!DOCTYPE yml_catalog SYSTEM "shops.dtd">
```

And because of this I cannot read the nodes - i have manually deleted this line and then can successfully read the nodes I want to get to.

Here is a snippet of the file:

Before download:

```
<yml_catalog date="2013-08-28 14:50">
<shop>
<name>DomProm.ru</name>
<company>DomProm.ru</company>
<url>http://www.domprom.ru</url>
<currencies>
<currency id="RUB" rate="1"/>
<currency id="USD" rate="33.4"/>
<currency id="EUR" rate="37.1"/>
</currencies>
<categories>
<category id="28">Крупная бытовая техника</category>
<category id="29" parentId="28">Стиральные машины</category>   
</categories>
<offers>
<offer id="27232" type="vendor.model" available="true">
```

After download:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?><!DOCTYPE yml_catalog SYSTEM "shops.dtd">
<yml_catalog date="2013-08-28 17:00">
<shop>
<name>DomProm.ru</name>
<company>DomProm.ru</company>
<url>http://www.domprom.ru</url>
<currencies>
<currency id="RUB" rate="1"/>
<currency id="USD" rate="33.4"/>
<currency id="EUR" rate="37.1"/>
</currencies>
<categories>
<category id="28">Êðóïíàÿ áûòîâàÿ òåõíèêà</category>
<category id="29" parentId="28">Ñòèðàëüíûå ìàøèíû</category>
<category id="30" parentId="28">Ïîñóäîìîå÷íûå ìàøèíû</category>
<category id="31" parentId="28">Õîëîäèëüíèêè/Ìîðîçèëüíûå êàìåðû/Âèííûå øêàôû</category>
</categories>
<offers>
<offer id="27232" type="vendor.model" available="true">
```

Here is some of the code i'm usingf to read it:

```
var document = new XmlDocument();

            try
            {
                // and load it with the contents of that file
                document.Load(downloadFileName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _keepItDry.WriteToEventLog(ex);
                // Trying to catch what is going on while the progrem is trying to load the downloaded file
                _keepItDry.AddTolistBox(DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " Error loading the file for " + scrape.Retailer.Description + " : " + ex.Message + " " + ex.StackTrace, _listBoxLog);
        }



 var domPromNodes = document.SelectNodes("//yml_catalog//shop//offers/offer");
                    if (domPromNodes != null)
                    {
                        foreach (XmlNode node in domPromNodes)
                        {
                            var title = "No Title"; var price = "No Price"; var modelNo = "No ModelNo"; var sku = "No Sku"; var inStock = "No Instock";
                            var deeplink = "No Deeplink"; var imageUrl = "No ImageUrl"; var brand = "No Brand";
```

if the doctype line is taken out var domPromNodes = document.SelectNodes("//yml_catalog//shop//offers/offer"); return results otherwise it fails.

Any help or any pointer to do with YML would be appreciated or a way to remove or ignore the

THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ignore the doctype which was making me unable to see the nodes i added the following:

```
  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                    doc.LoadXml(Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(downloadFileName), "<!DOCTYPE.+?>", string.Empty));
```

So this removed the DOCTYPE line and so allowed me to read the nodes